# Changing font in LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, times

I'm required to have my dissertation in Times New Roman. I'm using LuaLaTeX because it lets me use figures which are too big for the usual compiler. I've tried several ways to change the font:

```
\usepackage{times}
```

was already in the template provided, but doesn't seem to do anything (the document appears in the normal LaTeX font).

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
```

gives me undefined control sequence errors.

EDIT to give the whole code: My document is now like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn]{revtex4}    % Font size (10,11 or 12pt) and column number (one or two).

\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmainfont{times}[
  Extension      = .ttf ,
  BoldFont       = *bd ,
  ItalicFont     = *i ,
  BoldItalicFont = *bi
]

\usepackage[a4paper, left=1.85cm, right=1.85cm,
 top=1.85cm, bottom=1.85cm]{geometry}       % Defines paper size and margin length

%%%%% Document %%%%%
\begin{document}                     
Hello 123.
\end{document}
```

This gives a PDF in Times New Roman but with lots of Undefined Control Sequence Errors (none of which seem to be particularly helpful) and the top of the PDF looks like the picture below.
[image]

The log file is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e9IwV-Nmbza2UDfbFEDmv3xarpbJrfOB/view?usp=sharing

Am I doing something wrong - is there a simple way to change the font type that I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you shouldn't get get undefined command errors but it is impossible for anyone to debug if you do not show your input or what error you got. Edit your question to show the full error from the log file, in a code section so that line ends are preserved.

Comment: Don't use the package times with luatex. Simply `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}` should normally work, if you have the font.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! If you want to know all the ways of selecting a font in fontspec, see the fontspec manual section 2: Font selection. That said, your code compiles fine for me (including small caps). (on LuaTeX, Version 1.12.0; MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit)

Comment: `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}` gives the same error as above. When you say if I have the font - it's installed on my system, do I need to install it separately for this to work?

Comment: @TIF No, you do not have to install it in any special way. If it is in your OS's normal font path it should be found. Have you removed `\usepackage{times}` and only used `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}` without specifying anything extra in the square brackets?

Comment: @TivV yes all I have now is the `\documentclass` I used above, then `usepackage{fontspec}`, `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}`, then `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Show the log-file.

Comment: you need to update (at least) expl3 but as you have not shown the full log it's hard to tell you how best to do that as we can not even know if you are using miktex or texlive.

Comment: OK so miktex not texlive @UlrikeFischer is more reliable than me in that case:-)

Comment: I've uploaded the full log file, thanks for the patience.

Comment: Your tex system is outdated. You have a format from 2017 and luaotfload files from the same year. On the other side your expl3 files are from 2020 and don't fit to the old stuff. Either don't use lualatex or make a thorough update. Be aware that such an update after such a long time can change many things and lead to new problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless your TeX distribution is of neolithic vintage, the following code should work for you. Observe that loading the `fontspec` package is optional. The `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` font packages contain code that adjusts various settings depending on whether the document is compiled with pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX.

Aside: Instead of specifying `left=1.85cm, right=1.85cm, top=1.85cm, bottom=1.85cm` while loading the `geometry` package, do consider writing just `margin=1.85cm`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{revtex4}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.85cm]{geometry}  

%\usepackage{fontspec} % optional
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}                     
Hello 123.
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: There can be little justification these days for loading the `times` package, which was last updated ca 15 years ago. Its operational content consists of only three instructions:

```
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
```

This not only sets the document's "Roman" font to Times, but the default sans-serif font to Helvetica and (most problematically) the default monospaced font to Courier. You will most likely wish to exercise more specific control over the default sans-serif and monospaced fonts of your document.

Comment: EDIT: I put in `\usepackage{fontspec}` and it now works! Thanks a lot

Thanks, I've now thoroughly uninstalled and reinstalled Miktex. The template was from my department and it being 15 years old doesn't surprise me... However I'm now getting `! error: (file ntx-Regular-tlf-t1) (type 3): font ntx-Regular-tlf-t1 at 600 notfound! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!` when I try to compile.

Comment: @TIF - The error message sounds like the text and/or math fonts of the newtx font packages weren't installed properly. This, in turn, could be due to you either not (re)installing a *full* version of MikTeX or doing so only in admin mode but not in user mode as well (or vice versa). There are a ton of postings on this site about how to install/update MikTeX correctly and how to recover from an installation mistake. You might start at [How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/5001) (Sorry for being vague -- I don't use MikTeX myself.)

Comment: @TIF - The fact that the error message complains about type-3 fonts (which are raster fonts) not being found may also suggest that the type-1 outline fonts -- which is what one ought to be using in the 21st century! -- either weren't installed properly or weren't activated properly.